# ClosedXML iterate Worksheets programmatically.

Tags: c#, closedxml

In my Workbook, I have 4 worksheets with different tab names.
Say if they are named as follows: First, Second, Third, Fourth.

I could not find online how to iterate through each of the worksheet with say for for loop. As I am iterating, I would also like to capture the text on the Worksheet's tab (First, Second, etc.).

Comment: do a google search on the following `c# openxml read excel sheet`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can either grab the worksheets by name or id such as:

```
int index = 1; // note indexes are 1 based in ClosedXML
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(index);

string name = "First";
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(name);
```

Note you'll only want to do the above in instances where you know the sheet name and max id (example)

or you can iterate through the collection of worksheets in a workbook as such:

```
foreach (IXLWorksheet worksheet in workbook.Worksheets)
{
    Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Name); // outputs the current worksheet name.
    // do the thing you want to do on each individual worksheet.
}
```

You can find this information in visual studio by hitting F12 on your workbook object, you'll see all of the public methods/variables you're given access too.  `IXLWorksheet` and `IXLWorksheets` is what you're looking for.